# Badge in local notifications

Tags: swift, notifications, local, badge

When I register new notification - UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber - always 0, thats why I have always "1" in my badge. How I can update it in my local notifications?

```
 let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    let notificationInterval = components(forDay: settings.object.timeInterval)
    let requestIdentifier = settings.object.identifier
    content.badge = Swift.min(notificationsCount, UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1) as NSNumber
    content.body = settings.object.body
    content.title = settings.object.title
    content.categoryIdentifier = "categoryIdentifier"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.setValue(true, forKey: "shouldAlwaysAlertWhileAppIsForeground")
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: notificationInterval, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [request.identifier])
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Notification error")
        }
        print("Notification Register Success")
    }
```

Comment: Because you have used +1 as a badge number.

Comment: I add badge in local notifications so when I create it I don't know how many notifications are expected.